# How to write application that display sensor's data

Tags: mobile, sensors

i wante to write application that check all part(sensors & bluetooth & WiFi)of mobile and display information of any part of mobile to user...
can every one help me?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a question for you also :-) 
What is the bigger picture , or what problem you are trying to solve?

In general there are 2 Ways for Accessing sensors on Mobile:

### 1. Using Each Platform SDK & Language

Android : https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

iOS : [https://developer.apple.com/](https://developer.apple.com/ios)

Windows Mobile : https://dev.windows.com/en-us/

### 2. Using Some solution like Phone Gap, and write in Some Javasc Framework Like Angular

---

Hybrid Javascript Development:

Phonegap : http://phonegap.com/
Angular + Phonegap : http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: i want to write an android app
i search for instruction and example of this application

Comment: i'm sorry if i couldn't explain my problem better becouse my english kind a suck

Comment: Had you got your answer?
I will be glad to help more, I just need to understand what you are looking for....

Comment: i want to write application like (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calintat.sensors)but i'm very novice in android Programming.